# Sort vuetify simple table on button click

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I'm trying to sort calories column on simple vuetify table on click button. Following is the code which I was trying, but it's not working as expected.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
   methods: {
     sortCalories(){
        this.desserts.sort((a, b) => {
          if(typeof a[index] !== 'undefined'){
              if (!isDesc[0]) {
                 return a[index].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[index].toLowerCase());
              }
              else {
                  return b[index].toLowerCase().localeCompare(a[index].toLowerCase());
              }
            }
      });
      return this.desserts;
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <v-btn outlined @click="sortCalories">Sort</v-btn>
  <v-app id="inspire">


      <v-simple-table id="outputs-table">
        <template v-slot:default>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left">
                Name
              </th>
              <th class="text-left">
                Calories
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in desserts" :key="item.name">
              <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </template>
        </v-simple-tabl>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Also, I tried a javascript way that selecting elements and sort which of the following code

```
    sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.querySelectorAll("#outputs-table > .v-data-table__wrapper table");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this gives me undefined length error `document.querySelectorAll("#outputs-table > .v-data-table__wrapper table")` as it's not finding the table rows.

Any suggestions please how do I solve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you just used `<v-data-table/>` then controlling its `sort-by` props by an external button? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props

Comment: Should try that option but is there a way to hide the pagination and search for <v-data-table/>?

Comment: I believe you can. I haven't checked yet, but I think you can use `disable-pagination` prop of `<v-data-table/>`.

Comment: @Blackraspberryyy Yeah we can hide them using these props `:hide-default-footer="true"` but sort is not working on button click like on click of a button it's not triggering the column sorting. Any idea on this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to implement sorting on v-simple-table since there are no pre-built props to support that. However, you can completely do the same using `<v-data-table>` component. There's an [example on Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-sorting) which shows how to implement external sorting of v-data-tables using `sort-by` and `sort-desc` props.

The following example shows how you can implement external sorting of the "calories" column:

```html
<!-- To hide the pagination footer, use `hide-default-footer` prop -->
<v-data-table
  :items="desserts"
  :headers="headers"
  :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
  :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
  hide-default-footer
/>
<v-btn @click="sortCalories">Sort By Calories!</v-btn>
```

```js
// script

data () {
  return {
    sortBy: "calories",
    sortDesc: false,
    headers: [
      { text: "Name", value: "name",},
      { text: "Calories", value: "calories" },
    ],
    desserts: [...]
  }
},
methods: {
  sortCalories() {
    this.sortDesc = !this.sortDesc;
  }
}
```

Here's a sample demo on [codesandbox.io:](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-mclean-tp190?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I actually sorted It out with your suggestion in the morning itself. And it's absolutely working fine. thank you for your idea.